# Is there a gnu/unix command to both save a file without consuming stream?

Tags: unix, pipe, gnu

I seem to faintly remember some unix command that allows you to save out put while piping to the next program.

Eg.

```
echo "hello world!"  \
| mystery_command hello.txt \
| sed -E "s/hello/goodbye/g" \
> goodbye.txt
```

Would both create a file called hello.txt with "hello world!" as contents. and a file called goodbye.txt with "goodbye world!" as contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are thinking of [`tee(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html).

Comment: Thats the one! I knew it was something short and that I had used it before. Was on the tip of my tongue.